# How to find all the children for a parent child relation on one table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How will I find all the children under a folder? like in explorer you have a folder under neeth you have folder + folder  etc.

I want to find all folder under folder 2

I am using ORACLE db.

```
Folder 1
| |
| Folder 2
| |  |
| |  Folder 3
| |  |  |
| |  |  Folder 7
| |  |  |
| |  |  Folder 8
| |  |
| |  Folder 4
| |
| Folder 5
| |
| Folder 6 
|
Folder 10
```

This query gives me parent hierarchy.

```
SELECT AL_ITEM_ID, AL_FATHER_ID, AL_DESCRIPTION
FROM ALL_LISTS
CONNECT BY AL_ITEM_ID = PRIOR AL_FATHER_ID
start with AL_DESCRIPTION = 'Folder 7'
```

Comment: Just put prior on the other side `connect by prior al_item_id = al_father_id` and `start with` something higher up the hierarchy.

Comment: ok kind of working. If I put start with Folder 2 how will I not to show up folder 2 in the list? right now I am seeing folder 2, 3, 7, 8.  How can I get folder 3, 7, 8

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work:

```
Select
    al_item_id, 
    al_father_id,
    al_description
From 
    all_lists
Connect By 
    Prior al_item_id = al_father_id
Start With
    al_description = 'Folder 2'
Where
    Level > 1
```

If not, this almost certainly will, it depends whether the where gets evaluated before or after the connect by:

```
Select
    al_item_id,
    al_father_id,
    al_description
From (
    Select
        al_item_id, 
        al_father_id,
        al_description,
        level as lvl
    From 
        all_lists
    Connect By 
        Prior al_item_id = al_father_id
    Start With
        al_description = 'Folder 2'
    ) x
Where
    lvl > 1
```